# Order_by does not work with dynamic queries

Tags: elixir, ecto

I wanted to use `order_by` in query with dynamic, following the examples from [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/dynamic-queries.html):

```
def filter(params) do
  Post
  |> order_by(^filter_order_by(params["order_by"]))
end

def filter_order_by("published_at_desc"),
  do: dynamic([p], desc: p.published_at)
```

However what I get is:

```
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) Tuples can only be used in comparisons with literal tuples of the same size
    (ecto 3.1.7) expanding macro: Ecto.Query.dynamic/2
    (elixir 1.10.0-rc.0) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:233: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/7
```

There is also a second variant in their examples:

```
def filter_order_by("published_at_desc"),
  do: [desc: dynamic([p], p.published_at)]
```

This does not throw errors at compile, but at runtime instead:

```
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (ArgumentError) expected a field as an atom, a list or keyword list in `order_by`, got: `dynamic([c], c.inserted_at)`
        (ecto 3.1.7) lib/ecto/query/builder/order_by.ex:105: Ecto.Query.Builder.OrderBy.field!/2
        (ecto 3.1.7) lib/ecto/query/builder/order_by.ex:115: anonymous fn/2 in Ecto.Query.Builder.OrderBy.order_by!/2
        (elixir 1.10.0-rc.0) lib/enum.ex:1396: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
```

Comment: Changing `filter_order_by/1` to macro should do.

Comment: tried to, same error as in the second case. I guess the idea is to unquote the `dynamic` macro inside of the `filter_order_by` macro?

Comment: The idea is to avoid calling functions from the heart of [tag:ecto] meta voodoo magic and inject AST in place as is :)

Comment: Just to make sure: when testing macro you did indeed quoted the content `defmacro filter("..."), do: quote(do: [desc: dynamic([p], p.published_at)])` right?

Comment: sure that was exactly what I did.

Comment: I found their tests, and assuming they don't fail, the syntax provided by them is valid. https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/test/ecto/query/builder/group_by_test.exs#L37

Comment: Try to put the pin `^` inside the quoted AST in the macro. (Just a wild guess.)

Comment: Okay looks like I had to update my ecto dependency. The version I had was `3.1.7` and the current version is `3.4.1`